# Subdomain routing with Laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I have some trouble setting up subdomain routing properly. I think I have some problems regarding htaccess or virtual hosts on my machine.

My route look like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'store.munia.dk'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'Store\PageController@getHome'));
    Route::get('faq', array('as' => 'store.faq', 'uses' => 'Store\PageController@getFaq'));
    Route::get('documentation', array('as' => 'store.documentation', 'uses' => 'Store\PageController@getDocumentation'));
}
```

This works locally, but on my production machine, only the first route is available. The other routes will get a:

Not found: The requested URL /documentation was not found on this server.

From Apache.

Does anyone have an idea what would be the problem here? I am using the default htaccess file from Laravel and I haven't done any changes to the Apache setup.

Here's my virtual host conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try `store.munia.dk/index.php/faq`

Comment: This works. So how do I take care of this for subdomains? Removing the index.php. It is not needed without subdomains.

Comment: This sounds to me like the subdomain doesn't have enabled `.htaccess` (`AllowOverride All`) Are you able to change the vhost config?

Comment: I am. Though I might need some guidance.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the virtual host that belongs to the subdomain?

Comment: This is all default? I'll post it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable **mod_rewrite** in your apache2. You can do this simply in your webserver

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

after that you should restart your apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: @Stromgren How did this solve your problem if the rest of the application was working correctly? Just curious...

Comment: I had the same issue configuring my local server, and for me allowing mod_rewrite helped

Comment: Sure but if the OP had the application running already (under the main domain) mod_rewrite should already have been enabled or nothing would have worked. That's why I'm a bit puzzled...

Answer (score 3):

What's missing here is the `AllowOverride` option in your virtual host configuration. This option specifies if `.htaccess` files will be respected and their content applied. This should get it running:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```